# No www in Chrome Extension Manifest

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest, browser-extension

I'm trying to get a Chrome Extension for a site which redirects www.site.com to site.com

This manifest file works.

```
{
"name" : "MySite Redesign",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" : "Improves MySite visual design to make the interface cleaner.",
"content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["*://www.mysite.com/*"],
    "css" : ["style.css"]
  }]
}
```

This does not

```
{
"name" : "MySite Redesign",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" : "Improves MySite visual design to make the interface cleaner.",
"content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["mysite.com/*"],
    "css" : ["style.css"]
  }]
}
```

The error reads:

"Could not load extension from '/Users/colmtuite/dev/mysite-extension'. Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Missing scheme separator."

Comment: Use *://*.mysite.com/*. See https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/match_patterns.html.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try that.

Comment: Oops. Stackoverflow ate one asterisk:(

Comment: Broken links all around. Here you go: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the ["Match Patterns" docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) it's mandatory to specify a scheme. You can use `*` to mean "any scheme", "any subdomain" and "any path":

```
*://*.mysite.com/*
```